Combining Animations
I need some help with Blender. I'm trying to animate a robot for my master's thesis, but when I combine the armatures (I downloaded the movements from Mixamo), the robot always briefly spreads its arms and legs instead of transitioning smoothly into the other animations. Do you have any tips on how to solve this problem?
Thank you! 


There are lots of YT tutorials on combining Mixamo animations in Blender. Try  this one for instance.

please share the file, only keep the useful elements (armature, actions, strips), remove the other ones (so that we understand more easily): https://blend-exchange.com/
